# How can I refresh the current tab instead of opening a new one when CTRL+F5?

Tags: visual-studio, blazor, hot-reload

In the latest Visual Studio 2022, I changed a setting but do not remember which one. However, previously, when I hit CTRL+F5 the current browser tab was refreshed. Now, every time a new tab opens. How can I get back the previous behavior?
I think (but am not sure), I changed something with hot reload, because every save started a new build.

Not sure if it is relevant, but it is a Blazor Wasm app.